# How can I have class-wide constant in my React Component class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Usually I do this:

```
var tagSymbols = Object.freeze([
  '!',
  '+',
  '@'
]);
```

But then I know there is `const` from Babel (?).

```
const tagSymbols = Object.freeze([
  '!',
  '+',
  '@'
]);
```

Both return the same error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token (4:6)

  2 | 
  3 | class GeneralToDoListInput extends Component {
> 4 |   var tagSymbols = Object.freeze([
    |       ^
  5 |     '!',
  6 |     '+',
  7 |     '@'

Syntax error: Unexpected token (5:8)

  3 | class GeneralToDoListInput extends Component {
  4 | 
> 5 |   const tagSymbols = Object.freeze([
    |         ^
  6 |     '!',
  7 |     '+',
  8 |     '@'
```

Comment: Do you want this to be a public property for users of your, or just available inside this class's code?

Comment: Only for this class!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot put variable declarations inside a class body. That's just not allowed by the language. In ES6, the structure of a class declaration is basically

```
class Foo() {
  method1() {}
  method2() {}
  ...
}
```

The simplest solution would be to put the variable declaration outside of the class:

```
const tagSymbols = ...:
class GeneralToDoListInput extends Component {
  ...
}
```

Any code inside the class/module can access `tagSymbols`.

If it really has to be a class property you can either define a static getter:

```
class GeneralToDoListInput extends Component {
  static get tagSymbols() {
    return Object.freeze(...);
  }
}
```

Or assign it to the class after the declaration:

```
class GeneralToDoListInput extends Component {
  ...
}
GeneralToDoListInput.tagSymbols = ...;
```

Comment: I like this straightforward answer. I will go with static getter. It seems the most structured way but I fear it could make the codes longer.

Comment: Note that with the getter, every time you are accessing the property a new object is created. I'd go with the first approach if `tagSymbols` doesn't have to be accessed outside the class.

Comment: Isn't become global variable? If it put outside class? Additionally the second method is rather verbose `this.constructor.tagSymbols`.

Comment: Since you are working with react, I assume every file is actually a module. So no, it will be scoped to the module.

Comment: Cool, so it is actually become more like Python. Thanks mate!